# How to find the sender object in beforeunload event using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a requirement where user navigates from a page without saving the data, he need to be prompted with warning message saying that he is not saved the data. I have two links in my page 1. Yahoo and 2. Process. When the user clicks Yahoo he need to be prompted but when the user clicks Process he need not be prompted with the warning.

Below is the piece of code.

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="http://localhost/HLC/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hasChanged = false;
    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function (e) {
        if (hasChanged) {
            return "Want to close with out saving data?";
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(':input', document.myForm).bind("change", function () {
            hasChanged = true;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    Name:
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" />
    <br />
    <a id="redirect" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Click for yahoo.</a>
    <asp:Button ID="process" Text="Process" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside the function

```
    if ($(e.target).attr('id')=="redirect") {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Want to close with out saving data ?");
    }
```

Comment: $(e.target).attr('id') is returning value as undefined.

Comment: I saw your a tag has an id="redirect" and thus it ($(e.target).attr('id')) should return the id.

Comment: Use $('a').bind('click', function(){...}); for links.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check what triggered beforeunload event, because its target is set to document. 
But you can use some flag to decide if you should show confirmation:

```js
var hasChanged = false;
var ask = true;

$(window).bind("beforeunload", function (e) {
    if (hasChanged && ask) {
        return "Want to close with out saving data?";
    }
    ask = true; // depending on your processing handling you may want to reset this flag
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    // bind handler to turn off asking on button click
    $('#process').click(function () {
        ask = false;
    });  

    $(':input', document.myForm).bind("change", function () {
        hasChanged = true;
    });
});
```